# Navigation Menu change from Quotation to Sales Order in odoo10

Tags: action, odoo, odoo-10

I want to change status of Navigation menu from quotation to sale order when sales confirm. For this i tried to call sale order menu action into action_confirm. but didn't get up-to result.

also image attached below:[image]

**My action_confirm method code is here:**

```
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
    if self.partner_id.pet_names:
        for record in self.partner_id.pet_names:
        if record == self.pet_names_info:
            if self.order_line:
                for s in self.order_line:
                    if s.product_id:
                        if self.ser1 or self.ind_ser1:
                            self.confirm_rental_service()  # Rental service
                            self.confirm_rental_service_history()  # Rental history maintain
                        break

                res = super(sale_order_pet, self).action_confirm()
                if res:
                    self.confirm_email_template()
                action = self.env.ref('sale.action_orders').read()[0]
                action['res_id'] = self.ids[0]
                action['name'] = 'Sales Order'
                return action
            else:
                raise ValidationError("Please Add Products in Order Lines")
```